# How to make drawer button UnClickable in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

When my app starts, some data will load in background I don't want users to  click on `Drawer` icon at that time, So I did something like this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Title'),
    ),
    drawer: _isLoading ? null : HomeDrawer(),
    body: _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : _body(),
  );
}
```

In this case, when the app loads the drawer button is notVisible
[image]

After loading, the button comes back.
[image]

**What I want is**
The drawer button should be visible during loading state but it should not be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
bool _isLoading = false;
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _key,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("App"),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: _isLoading ? null : () => _key.currentState.openDrawer(),
      ),
    ),
    drawer: YourDrawer(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me again. Really sorry I haven't tried it yet. I will let you I a day or two. My exams are going on these days. Hope you understand.

Comment: No problem, take your time and let me know. Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks for help again.

Answer (score 1):

I used the custom drawer button where I assign/remove it's onPressed event based on the `_isLoaded` variable. After 3 seconds since the page load I set the `_isLoaded` variable value to `true` which rerenders the page and enables the drawer button and hides the loader.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isLoaded = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this._apiCallSample();
  }

  void _apiCallSample() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        this._isLoaded = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: !this._isLoaded ? null : () => this._scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        ),
        title: Text("Drawer"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            if(!this._isLoaded) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            return Text("Loaded!");
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Drawer"),
        ),
      ),
      key: this._scaffoldKey,
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to prevent the user from clicking **anywhere** on the page then use the [AbsorbPointer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html).

> When absorbing is true, this widget prevents its subtree from receiving pointer events by terminating hit testing at itself.

Comment: Ofcourse adding custom button came to my mind also, but is there any property or any way by which we can make Drawer button unClickable

Comment: Not that I can think of. Try using AbsorbPainter.